# Visual Studio Code Live Server

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

I am new to web development and new to visual studio code. I had installed live server for an old project and worked great. But now when I try to open up a new project and launch it with live server it keeps opening up the old project. I had tried to remove and install live server again but the same thing happens. I don't know what is going on and really like live server but don't know why this happens.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have live Server installed on your local? if yes! right-click on your HTML code environment e.g `index.html` on the project you are working on and `select open with live Server`

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9v9qt.png)

Answer (score 0):

Do you open your Live Server with the shortcut keys? If so, intead of doing that, go to the project you're working on and right click anywhere on the line of code and click on "Open with Live Server"

Comment: Thanks. But I don't use any shortcut keys. I right-click and do push "Open with Live Server" but still opens the old project.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).